# how to send two different messages to two different users phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am sending mails to two different persons, two different messages one for user and one for admin.

```
  $message1='hello user'      
  $message2='hello admin'
  $email = 'user@email.com'
  $adminemail = 'admin@email.com';

  require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  $mail->isHTML();
  $mail->IsSMTP(); 
  $mail->setFrom('admin@mysite.com', 'admin site'); 
  $mail->AddAddress( $email);
  $mail->Subject  = $subject;
  $mail->Body     =$message1;
  $mail->Send();
  //message for admin 
  $mail->Body     =$message2;
  //$adminemail = $generalsettings[0]["admin_email"]; 

   $mail->AddAddress($adminemail);
   $mail->Send();
```

But as a user I am receiving the message twice.. How to send two different messages to two different users.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to clear the recipients list before you add the new address for the second message. If you don't do that, the first recipient will receive the second message as well:

```
...
$mail->Body     =$message1;
$mail->Send();

//message for admin 

// Remove previous recipients
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
// alternative in this case (only addresses, no cc, bcc): 
// $mail->ClearAddresses();

$mail->Body     =$message2;
//$adminemail = $generalsettings[0]["admin_email"]; 

// Add the admin address
$mail->AddAddress($adminemail);
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: thank you so much I wanted to loop through them, using this i can easily now

Comment: Thanks it really hepled, I trying many thing but always just stucked.

Answer (score 7):

You can initiate phpmailer class two times.

```
$message1='hello user'      
$message2='hello admin'
$email = 'user@email.com'
$adminemail = 'admin@email.com';

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->setFrom('admin@mysite.com', 'admin site'); 
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message1;
$mail->Send();

$mail2 = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail2->isHTML();
$mail2->IsSMTP(); 
$mail2->setFrom('admin@mysite.com', 'admin site'); 
$mail2->AddAddress($adminemail);
$mail2->Subject = $subject;
$mail2->Body = $message2;
$mail2->Send();
```

This should work too:

```
$message1='hello user'      
$message2='hello admin'
$email = 'user@email.com'
$adminemail = 'admin@email.com';

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->setFrom('admin@mysite.com', 'admin site'); 
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message1;
$mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAddresses();

$mail->AddAddress($adminemail);
$mail->Body = $message2;
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your second option because it's less code but when I add the last $mail->send() the mail gets sent 3 times. But when I remove it, it's sent twice which should be the norm. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

`$mail->ClearAllRecipients();` // It removes old emails, After sending old emails use this code and again use addaddress() and send other users